# So Many Tutorial Guides, But How Can I Filter A Drupal 7 View To Show Nodes With A Taxonomy Term?

Tags: drupal

Although many post exits for this topic, no one seem to guide the user on how to go about this feature. I need to filter a view block such that it displays nodes with specific taxonomy terms. I have a taxonomy vocab called Sections containing terms like Analysis, Sports e.t.c and my Article content type has a filed tagging them with the terms. In other words, Article nodes are tagged with term(s) from the Sections vocab. I just need a way to display a block, with say nodes tagged with Sports

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed any D6 tutorials, the major change is that taxonomy terms are now tagged as a field.

So create the View on Node table, and add fields as you want. Then, add a filter to the field's name that you used to tag terms in the Sections vocabulary.

You will be given a multi-select list to choose which terms should be filtered.

Comment: Thanks for your time and for the response. OK, here is what I did.
1. for Add filter criteria I selected "Taxonomy Filter" and then I checked the Taxonomy Filter: Node Taxonomy Filter checkbox
2. Under Configure filter criterion: Taxonomy Filter: Node Taxonomy Filter, I selected the Is Operator and also selected Sections as the Vocabulary.
3. I expect that following (2) above I should be presented with a way to select the term(s) I want to filter to, but this does not happen.
Some people have suggested Contextual Filters, but I find that even more "complex". Please where am I missing it.

Comment: Under Add contextual filters I selected Content: Has taxonomy term ID and then for the Configure contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID screen I selected Provide default value  which exposes a Type combo and a Field combo
2. For the Type combo I selected Field Value From Current Node/Term
3. For the Field combo I selected field_op_section_term which is the term reference field.
4. There is still no way to select the term(s) I want to filter to, and my many combination of selections did not also filter the view to nodes having the term(s) in question.

Please where am I missing it.